# How to read .doc (word 2003 and older) files from AWS S3 with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, doc

I'm building a resume parser and the input data has 3 different formats: .doc, .docx, .pdf.

So far I've tried different methods:

1. Using `antiword` library with linux ubuntu (WSL2) with local doc files and it works perfectly, nonetheless if since i'm working with AWS S3 objects i can't figure out how to make antiword work with remote files (public url) so this didn't work for me
2. using `win32client`, it does work with local files but not with remote files plus this code will be executed from a Linux instance and there is no alternative for win32client

First I get every object in the S3 bucket, then and transform de body or content to `io.Bytes`. For pdf files I'm using pdfminer and it works, for docx files i'm using python-docx and works as well, but i have no idea how to make this work with doc files. The following code extracts the s3 object get its extension and then extracts the text from it:

```
def get_selection_raw(path):
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3",
                    region_name='us-east-2') ###we have to add secret and access key
    rose_bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
    for resume in rose_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path):
        key = resume.key
        body = resume.get()['Body'].read()
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        buffer.write(body)
        ext = re.search('\.[a-z]+$', key)
        ###handle folder path first, its nonetype
        if ext == None:
            continue
        elif ext.group() == '.docx':
            document = Document(buffer)
            string = "\n".join([paragraph.text for paragraph in document.paragraphs])
            #print(string)
        elif ext.group() == '.pdf':
            rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
            retstr = StringIO()
            codec = 'utf-8'
            laparams = LAParams()
            device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
            password = ""
            maxpages = 0
            caching = True
            pagenos=set()
            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(buffer, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
                #fp.close()
                #device.close()
                #retstr.close()
            string = retstr.getvalue()
            #print(string)
        elif ext.group() == '.doc':
            # no idea what to do
```

Comment: It's normally easier to simply download the file from Amazon S3 to the local disk, then process it as normal. That way, libraries can interact with the file like they expect, and there's no need to use streams.